# How can I show the space with norm $\|f\| = \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} (1+|x|^2)^m |f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}$ is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $m\in \mathbb R$. How can I show that $X = \{f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C| \|f\|<\infty\}$ with the norm
$$
\|f\| = \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}  (1+|x|^2)^m |f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}, 
$$
is complete?

Comment: Hard to tell, since you don't say what  $X $ is.

Comment: it is just measurable function family on R^n with the norm is finite

Comment: There's an isometric isomorphism $X \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I want to show this directly, with cauchy sequences

Comment: You should write something about the background of the problem, your thoughts and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.

Find an equivalent Cauchy sequence $(g_n)$ in $L^2$.

Use a well-known result to find $g\in L^2$, such that $g_n\to g$ in $L^2$.

Find $f$ in $X$, related to $g$, such that $f_n\to f$ in $X$.